# Typo3: How do I get all user groups for a backend-user and vice versa

Tags: typo3

I am trying to write an extension where backend users can write emails to users of the same group. I know how to find backend users and also groups. But I can not find any way to find out which group a user belongs to and which other users are in this group.
I hope someone here can help me. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I inject the backend user repositiory in my controller

```
/**
 * beUserRepository
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\BackendUserRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $beUserRepository = null;
```

And get all Backend-User with this statement:

```
$allUsers = $this->beUserRepository->findAll();
```

I thougth i could get all UserGroups by something like:

```
foreach ($allUsers as $user)
    {   
        $groups = $user->getUserGroup();
        ...
    }
```

But it seems nothing like this exists.

Comment: Repositories for oldest parts of system like `pages`, `users` (FE/BE), etc, are very simple and returns just arrays from DB queries, the same is with `BackendUserRepository::class`. In that case, the fastest solution is writing a custom repository which finds records by your own SQL (probably via `QueryBuilder`). This is an old question, so I won't answer it with sample, but if you'll need it still, point me in the comment, I'll find some code I wrote some time ago for this. Where suggested by @NextThursday is correct, although it may be written better (i.e. with `QueryBuilder`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a database table field `be_users.usergroup` which contains a comma separated list of `be_groups.uid`.

You could use that for a database lookup. Often ppl use a SQL query like

`WHERE usergroup LIKE "<myid>,%" OR  usergroup LIKE "%,<myid>,%" OR  usergroup LIKE "%,<myid>" OR  usergroup = "<myid>"`

to check if a comma separated field includes  (although some SQL dialects might have easier ways).

To get an idea how and where things are stored from other tables a look into the TCA files might help, e.g. https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/TCA/be_users.php#L63

### Concerning your update:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/BackendUserObject/ points to the API class
https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_authentication_1_1_backend_user_authentication.html
where you can find some functions concerning similar tasks to extract a 
best practice.

Keep in mind that non-admin users won't have access to much information, thus you need to leave the user context (i.e. you can't use `BackendUserAuthentication`, but need to use the underlying methods).

### Concerning your general idea:

Keep in mind that groups can be arranged in a complex hierarchy with inheritance. Thus it might not be easy to list "other group users", as depending on the scenario you might need to add users of parent-groups or child-groups.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I just thought there was already a method without going back to SQL.
I added some samplecode.